# How to disable parent <ScrollView> when child is scrolling?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I have multiple nested scroll views as such:

```
<ScrollView  nestedScrollEnabled={true}>

   <ScrollView  nestedScrollEnabled={true}> ... </ScrollView>

   ...

</ScrollView>
```

Is there a way to disable parent scroll when the child is scrolling?

The current behaviour is that when the child is completely scrolled the parent scrolls along with it, is it possible to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a state for the scroll view you want to disable,

```
const [isScrollViewOpen, setIsScrollViewOpen]=useState(false)

  <ScrollView
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
   nestedScrollEnabled={true}
   scrollEnabled={isScrollViewOpen}
<
... your code
</ScrollView>
```

And on the other ScrollView setIsScrollViewOpen using the onScroll

```
   <ScrollView
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      nestedScrollEnabled={true}
      contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      onScroll={()=>setIsScrollViewOpen(true)} >
  ...your code
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but this doesn't seem to give the desired result smoothly i.e. when scrolling fast it doesn't always work